# Custom top tab bar with only text swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to create a tab bar at the top of my page and contain only text, and when one clicked it will change the text color and underline the selected item... as shown in the image below...

[image]

I searched a lot but didn't find something to help me achieve this..

Can someone please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: It's segment control (https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/controls/segmented-controls/). You can get some here https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=segment+control&type=Repositories

Comment: check this ..https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Comment: https://medium.com/michaeladeyeri/how-to-implement-android-like-tab-layouts-in-ios-using-swift-3-578516c3aa9

Comment: You can also use page menu library for this.check this link.
https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu

Answer (score 0):

Take Three Buttons and three imageviews.take action for three buttons and take outlets for images and labels as given below . use this link to easy identify.it's perfectly working for you. [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0DIh.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

@IBOutlet weak var imgDetails: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgPassword: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imglocations: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var lblDetailsTittle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblPasswordTittle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblLocationTittle: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


  //if you want select by default Details use this code otherwise uncomment it.

imgDetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
imgPassword.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
imglocations.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

lblDetailsTittle.textColor = UIColor.black
lblPasswordTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
lblLocationTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

}


@IBAction func btnDetailsTouchUpInSide(_ sender: Any)
{
    imgDetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    imgPassword.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imglocations.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    lblDetailsTittle.textColor = UIColor.black
    lblPasswordTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    lblLocationTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
}
@IBAction func btnPasswordTouchUpInSide(_ sender: Any)
{
    imgPassword.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    imgDetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imglocations.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    lblPasswordTittle.textColor = UIColor.black
    lblLocationTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    lblDetailsTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
}

@IBAction func btnLocationsTouchUpInSide(_ sender: Any)
{
    imglocations.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    imgDetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imgPassword.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    lblLocationTittle.textColor = UIColor.black
    lblPasswordTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    lblDetailsTittle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
}


}
```